# How to resolve IHttpContextAccessor dependent DbContext in controller

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET Core MVC 5 application using Entity Framework Core.

For registration interface is created:

```
public interface IDummyInterfaceForRegistration<T>
{
}
```

Context is derived from Entity Framework Core DbContext class:

```
public partial class EevaContext : DbContext, IDummyInterfaceForRegistration<EevaContext>
{ 
    public EevaContext(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
```

IHttpContextAccessor object creation is registered in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddTransient<IDummyInterfaceForRegistration<EevaContext>, EevaContext>();
```

Home Controller declares this class as dependency:

```
    public HomeController(EevaContext ctx, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
```

Trying to run application raises exception

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Eeva.Entity.EevaContext' while attempting to activate
> 'Store.Controllers.HomeController'.

How to fix this ?

Comment: You're not registering a MyappContext in ConfigureServices, so the DI container cannot inject it into the constructor of HomeController.

Comment: I created dummy interface and registered but same error is thrown. I updated question

Comment: You need to declare the interface in your Controller constructor, not the concrete type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For registration interface is created:
>
> ```
> public interface IDummyInterfaceForRegistration<T>
> {
> }
> ```

Unless you have other reasons, you don't need an interface just for registration.

Then replace:

```
services.AddTransient<IDummyInterfaceForRegistration<EevaContext>, EevaContext>();
```

with:

```
services.AddTransient<EevaContext>();
```

Then your controller will receive an instance of EevaContext concrete class.